# MySQL Innodb_row_lock_current_waits is 2^64 - 1

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL 5.6 server which we monitor using Nagios.

Over the weekend, it's started complaining about the Innodb_row_lock_current_waits, which currently has a value of 18446744073709551615, yes, that's more than 10^19! As I understand it, this value is the number of current row locks. Basically, I don't believe it, that number is far too large?

As Phil pointed out, the number is 2^64 - 1, so now my question is: Why is MySQL returning this number, it must be an overflow/error code of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

There is a open bug report on this for MySQL 5.6.14

[Bug #71520 Constantly increasing Innodb_row_lock_current_waits value](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71520)

From the bug report, note this entry

> [25 Jun 2015 6:58] Zhenye Xie in my environment, I got a strange
>   value. (-1 as uint64)
>
> ```
> mysql> show status where Variable_name = 'Innodb_row_lock_current_waits';
>
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+
> | Variable_name                 | Value                |
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+
> | Innodb_row_lock_current_waits | 18446744073709551615 |
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.06 sec)
> ```
>
> in lock0wait.cc, srv_stats.n_lock_wait_current_count.inc() srv_stats.n_lock_wait_current_count.dec(); is not thread safe.
>   srv_stats is a global variable, but it has just a lock on trx
>   surrounds changing the value.

You were right when you said `it must be an overflow/error code of some sort`

As recent as Jun 14 of this year, this issue may or may not exist in MySQL 5.7.11

> [14 Jun 9:55] Ángel OR Good morning,
>
> I am seeing this in MySQL 5.7.11-log:
>
> ```
> mysql> show status like '%Innodb_row_lock_current%';
>
> +-------------------------------+-------+
> | Variable_name                 | Value |
> +-------------------------------+-------+
> | Innodb_row_lock_current_waits | 45    |
> +-------------------------------+-------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> select count(*) from information_schema.innodb_lock_waits;
>
> +----------+
> | count(*) |
> +----------+
> |        0 |
> +----------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> select version();
> +------------+
> | version()  |
> +------------+
> | 5.7.11-log |
> +------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be 'continually increasing'. It suddenly jumped from 0 to this value.

Comment: You just verified that the bug is very much alive and kicking.

Comment: My bug seems different from the one linked - the value does not 'continually increase', the value jumped from 0-'overflow', it did not pass through intermediate values. I see a comment in the linked bug which mentions the same behaviour that I see, but it's not the same as reported in the bug description.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has other cases of -1 being stored into an UNSIGNED field.  Report it via http://bugs.mysql.com , then don't worry about it.